# working with cell on tableview using swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, uistoryboardsegue

I am developing a app using Swift 2. In my app I am parsing JSON data to a table view. When I tap a cell it successfully moves to another view controller but I am unable to fetch the json data.

This is the code in my view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    var cell = self.TableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableCell
    let strbookdetail : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("booking_detail") as! NSString
    let strdrop : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("drop_address") as! NSString
    cell.Bookdetail.text=strbookdetail as String
    cell.Dropaddress.text=strdrop as String
    return cell as CustomTableCell

}

//It helps to parse JSON  data to table view.

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    TableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let tripcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UpcomingController") as! Secondcontroller
    navigationController?.pushViewController(tripcontroller, animated: true)

}
```

When tapping on the cell it helps to move to other view controller `SecondController`

In my `SecondController` I have two `UILabel`s.  In those labels I want to show data i.e `strbookdetail` and `strdrop`

How can I pass a reference between the two view controllers?

Comment: [This topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/434/passing-data-between-view-controllers#t=201611220747564284945) in the documentation might help you

Comment: are you push the VC is successfully, but you are not written the code for pass the data

Comment: i have give connections through storyboard everything works fine but in my table view there is cell..each cell has different data so if i tap on particular cell it should fetch data according to their cell

Comment: yes @Anbu.Karthik....i not written code to pass data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to do using `property` pass data:

In 2th `vc`:

```
var dataFromBeforeVC:[String:String] = [String:String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    initData ()

}

func initData()  {

    // set data  strbookdetail and strdrop to labelOne & labelTwo

    labelOne.text = dataFromBeforeVC["strdrop"]
    labelTwo.text = dataFromBeforeVC["strbookdetail"]


}
```

In 1th `vc`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    TableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let tripcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UpcomingController") as! Secondcontroller

    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)!

    let strbookdetail : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("booking_detail") as! NSString
    let strdrop : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("drop_address") as! NSString
    tripcontroller.dataFromBeforeVC = [
        "strdrop":strbookdetail,
        "strdrop":strbookdetail
    ]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tripcontroller, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: am created outlet for the label box in second controller...how do i give reference to it in my second controller viewdidload method

Comment: Don't set the label's directly from the first view controller, pass the data and use this in a function such as `viewWillAppear` to update the labels.  I would also suggest you create a Struct to hold your parsed JSON data instead of indexing into a dictionary all the time.  Also you should use `String` rather than `NSString`

Comment: @raj kumar see my EDITED answer!